# py2app: How can I run tests using the bundled python interpreter?

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I use [py2app](http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/index.html) to package my application.  A few quick notes about my app:

- It uses a special python executable (i.e. non-system python), which py2app includes in the bundle.
- I explicitly exclude a few packages from site-packages.zip using the py2app recipe feature.

In the past, I've sometimes had issues with my app bundle because I forgot to exclude certain packages from site-packages.zip.  This was easy to fix once I discovered the problem, but I wasn't quick to discover it because the packages in question *mostly* worked.  The problem only showed itself after testing special cases that happen to exercise specific submodules in the problematic dependency.

In order to avoid problems like this in the future, I want to run a test suite using the same exact interpreter that py2app includes in my bundle.  For that to work, I need the proper environment setup that is somehow automatically created when the app starts up (including `PYTHONPATH`, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc.).

Just using `./dist/MyBundle.app/Contents/MacOS/python` to run my tests doesn't seem to do the trick.  What's the recommended method to run tests on the fully built app bundle itself?

Comment: It's been awhile since I've used py2app, but I recall the info.plist of the app containing a bunch of python environment stuff.

Comment: What are you using to run tests? Seems you could just create a custom packaged version of your app that calls the test entry point rather than starting your app as usual...

Comment: How did you manage to get py2app to bundle the non-system executable? I am trying to achieve this, without success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845112/app-built-with-non-system-python-in-pyenv-not-runnable-on-other-machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the --extra-scripts option introduced in py2app 0.7 to include a second script that starts the test in the application bundle and use that to run the tests.

I agree that it would be nice to have a way to run scripts with the application environment, could you file an issue for this in py2app's repository at https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app?

Comment: Thanks, @Ronald!.  The --extra-scripts option will work for my purposes.  As requested, I just added an issue to the py2app issue tracker for a more general solution.