# App built with non-system Python using py2app in pyenv not runnable on other machines

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, py2app, pyenv

My understanding was that as long as a non-Apple-default Python is employed to build, that the end-user need not install Python him/herself to execute a py2app-built app. In developing and testing the app in my own environment, I obviously have Python installed. Specifically, I built in a **pyenv** with with a python.org install, not Apple's own. Yet when I give the app to an end-user who doesn't have Python installed, she gets:

> A Python runtime could not be located. You may need to install a
>   framework build of Python, or edit the PyRuntimeLocations array in
>   this application's Info.plist file.

The second line is concerning; if what it states is true, then a separate app instance would need to be built for every possible location of an end-user's install e.g `/usr/bin`, `/Library/Frameworks` etc.

**UPDATE:** Info.plist defines:

```
    <key>PythonExecutable</key>
<string>/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python</string
```

Yet the end-user in question only has a system install in `/usr/bin`.

Does this mean that every end-user needs to have an externally-installed Python, and it must live in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

What if they don't have a non-Apple Python? What if they have a non-Apple Python but it's not 2.6? How can this somewhat hardcoded dependency be avoided?

Comment: `find MyAppliation.app -name Python.framework` returns nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

py2app automatically defaults to `--semi-standalone` mode if it thinks you are using the system interpreter.  Your interpreter from Python.org shouldn't count as a "system" interpreter, but you could see what `py2app` thinks using this command:

```
$ python -c "import py2app.build_app; print py2app.build_app.is_system()"
False
```

One issue to watch out for: After I installed a Python.org interpreter today, `bash` didn't update it's `hash` cache, causing strange incompatibilities when I launched python.  I had to type `hash -r python` to reset the cache and make sure the correct version of python was getting used.  (Another way to fix this is to log out and log in again.)  I suppose it's possible that the same issue could have caused `py2app` to be confused about whether or not you were using the system python.

If that doesn't do the trick, then try installing your python interpreter to a weird location, like `~/mypython` or something like that, just to make sure there's no way it can be confused for a system python.

As a last resort, I suppose you could just hack the `py2app` source code so that `is_system()` always returns `False`.  Not sure if that would have any adverse consequences, though.

PS -- Here's a little tutorial on using `py2app` with a `conda`-packaged application:
https://github.com/stuarteberg/helloworld  Not exactly relevant to your problem here, but you could compare it with your own setup and look for any conspicuous differences.

Comment: https://github.com/stuarteberg/helloworld is quite useful to make py2app work with conda